# Difference between await and using discards

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, synchronous

What is the difference between the below two lines.

```
await SkillReporterDatabase.Database.SaveAsync(someObject);

_ = SkillReporterDatabase.Database.SaveAsync(someObject);
```

Which one is preferred? Sometimes when I face some issue with await, I use _ = and it solves the problem. I couldn't see any resources online which explains the difference between these two.

Comment: Yes. Discarding the return value of `SaveAsync` (which is some form of `Task`) will not actually ensure that `SaveAsync` runs to completion. Same as not awaiting it

Comment: You didn't await the second call

Comment: I don’t think that your second line have ever solved anything at all... It’s not even executed. It will just return a non running Task and that gets discarded.

Comment: @LegacyCode *"It’s not even executed. It will just return a non running Task"* - That's not correct. You should give it a try. `SaveAsync()` will run normally, you will just have no way to know when or if it completes. It's usually called "fire and forget".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The *difference* is that the discard (`_`) doesn't care about what happens in `SaveAsync` once it becomes asynchronous, which it presumably *does* do; this has two important side effects:

1. you won't know if the save failed
2. if you perform any other operations via `Database`, you're *probably* going to be running overlapped operations on a single context/connection, which is not usually a supported scenario

So in this case, `await` is probably preferred. There *are* times when it is OK to discard a task, but that usually means when you start something in the background that has *no further interaction* with the current flow.

Answer (score 2):

Without the await, later operations will not be blocked by the `SaveAsync` call and will therefore run concurrently. The discard is just saving the Task (a task is conceptually a bit like a progress bar), not the result of the Task the way the awaited call is.

so `SaveAsync` returns a `Task` (like a promise in JavaScript). Calling `await` on that `Task` will block until the task completes and returns a result. Not calling await and instead just throwing away the Task is like throwing away a pointer in C++ -- your program will start the task and then forget about it -- it may still complete but the code in this method will never find out whether it does or not.

Comment: Using the word "block" isn't entirely correct. Using `await` yields control to the calling code, and schedules a continuation once the `Task` has completed.